# How to Print DIV asp.net dynamic contents from database SQL

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, printing

I have a 5 image on database SQL as example, and then I use ASP.net to location that images placed into div, I want to print it with javascript or jquery or other. How to print it dynamically ex. looping until specific image each row on database,

Thank You,

Comment: Do you mean "print" as in use a printer to print a picture on to a piece of paper, or like print the file name on the screen?

Comment: Yes sir, I want to use print a picture on to a piece of paper but the question how to print dynamically each row database on div printing with using jquery or other?

Comment: do you have sample code to start with ?